# Backward Compatibility problems with old Microsoft SQL Server 2000 DTS package files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, etl, backwards-compatibility, dts

We have some old Microsoft SQL Server 2000 DTS package files ( that have dts extension ).
I need to import the old  DTS package files to a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Studio.

I read the following guide, but I fail to find any Legacy folder under the Management folder within the  Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Object Explorer View:

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645945(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645945%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

I need to import the Microsoft SQL Server 2000 DTS package files into the  Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Studio.

Please suggest how I can resolve the issue

Follow Up on my experience in importing the DTS packages to my Microsoft SQL Server 2008 DTS package files:

Managing DTS packages in SQL Server Management Studio requires the SQL Server 2000 Data Transformation Services (DTS) runtime. To install the DTS runtime, on your SQL Server 2008 R2 installation media, locate and run the Windows Installer package for SQL Server 2005 Backward Compatibility (SQLServer2005_BC*.msi). You can also download the DTS runtime from the SQL Server Feature Pack page on the Microsoft Download Center. (Microsoft.SqlServer.DtsObjectExplorerUI)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.ObjectExplorerUI.PackageUtils.LoadPkgInfoFromStorageFile(String sUNCPath)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.ObjectExplorerUI.LegacyActionBase.ShowPkgBrowser(String& sPackageName, String& sPackageID, String& sPackageVersionID, StorageLocation location, String sPackagePathName)

---

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500440%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Support for SQL Server 2000 DTS in SQL Server 2008 R2
SQL Server 2008 R2
Other Versions
4 out of 6 rated this helpful - Rate this topic

Although SQL Server 2000 Data Transformation Services (DTS) is deprecated, SQL Server 2008 provides optional 32-bit management, run-time, and design-time support for packages that were created by using the DTS tools and object model. (For more information about the deprecation of DTS, see Data Transformation Services (DTS).)
NoteNote

For SQL Server 2008 R2, there have been no changes to the content that is listed in this topic.
Important noteImportant

The features described in this topic, including run-time support for DTS packages, require the manual installation of additional, optional components that are not available during setup. For more information, see the sections, "Installing run-time support for DTS packages " and "Installing design-time support for DTS packages," later in this topic.

Be aware that not all DTS functionality is supported in all circumstances. The following sections describe exactly what DTS functionality is supported in SQL Server 2008.
Limited SQL Server 2000 DTS Functionality on 64-bit Operating Systems

SQL Server 2008 does not include support for DTS in the following circumstances:

```
There is no 64-bit design-time or run-time support for DTS packages. On a 64-bit computer, DTS packages, and Integration Services packages that run DTS packages, can run only in 32-bit mode. For more information, see How to: Install Support for Data Transformation Services Packages.

There is also no 32-bit design-time or run-time support for DTS packages on Itanium-based operating systems. Therefore, you cannot create, view, modify, or run DTS packages on Itanium-based operating systems.
```

Supported SQL Server 2000 DTS Functionality

SQL Server 2008 includes support for the following DTS features:

```
The DTS runtime, the object model that it exposes, and the dtsrun.exe command prompt utility.

The Execute DTS 2000 Package task, for executing DTS packages within Integration Services packages.

The ActiveX Script task, for backward compatibility only.

The DTS Package Migration Wizard, for migrating DTS packages to the Integration Services package format.

The Upgrade Advisor rules for DTS packages, for identifying potential issues that may be encountered when migrating packages.
```

Important noteImportant

The Execute DTS 2000 Package task, the ActiveX Script task, and the DTS Package Migration Wizard are installed when you select Integration Services for installation. However, these components are not fully functional without the manual installation of additional, optional components that are not available during Setup. For more information, see the section, "Installing run-time support for DTS packages," later in this topic.

The remainder of this topic discusses in more detail the DTS functionality that SQL Server 2008 supports. Use the following links to quickly connect you to this content:

General information

```
    General compatibility between DTS and SSIS

    Managing DTS packages
```

Designing and running DTS packages

```
    Installing run-time support for DTS packages

    Running DTS packages at the command prompt

    Running DTS packages from SQL Server Agent jobs

    Running DTS packages from Integration Services packages

    Installing design-time support for DTS packages
```

Migrating DTS packages

```
    Migrating DTS packages

    Migrating dtsrun commands to dtexec commands
```

Limited support

```
    Support for ODBC data sources

    Support for Repository packages

    Support for DTS Packages in SQL Server Express
```

General Compatibility between SQL Server 2000 DTS and Integration Services

DTS and Integration Services are completely different products. Integration Services is not a version upgrade from DTS. Therefore, there are no software conflicts between DTS and Integration Services. You can do the following procedures:

```
Install both DTS and Integration Services on the same server.

Run both DTS and Integration Services packages on the same server. Even if the SQL Server 2000 tools are not present on the server, you can run DTS packages by using the updated version of the DTS runtime that is installed with Integration Services.

Save DTS packages in the msdb database of an instance of SQL Server 2000, or an instance that is running SQL Server 2005 or a later version. However, you can save SQL Server 2008 Integration Services packages only on an instance that is running SQL Server 2008.

Use an optional download of the DTS Designer to modify DTS packages even if the SQL Server 2000 tools are not present on the computer. However, you cannot open or modify DTS packages directly in Business Intelligence Development Studio.
NoteNote

For information about how to download the updated version of the DTS Designer, see the section, Installing Design-time Support for SQL Server 2000 DTS Packages.
```

When you upgrade an existing instance of SQL Server to SQL Server 2008, the system tables (for example, sysdtspackages) that DTS uses in the msdb database remain intact. DTS packages are not automatically migrated. For information about how to migrate packages, see the section, Migrating DTS packages.

Arrow icon used with Back to Top linkBack to the top of this section
Managing SQL Server 2000 DTS Packages

After you install the optional run-time support for DTS as described in the section, "Installing run-time support for DTS packages," you can manage DTS packages from SQL Server Management Studio. These DTS packages can be stored in an instance of SQL Server 2000, or imported to and stored in an instance that is running SQL Server 2005 or a later version.
Important noteImportant

For important information about how to secure DTS packages, see Securing DTS Packages Stored in SQL Server.

To view DTS packages in Management Studio, first connect to an instance of SQL Server. (Do not connect to an instance of Integration Services.) Then, in the Object Browser under the Management\Legacy\Data Transformation Services node, you will be able to perform the following tasks:

```
When you select the Data Transformation Services node in Management Studio, you can view and open packages, import them to SQL Server from structured storage files, or start the DTS Package Migration Wizard.

When you select an individual DTS package in Management Studio, you can open the package to modify it, migrate it, export it to a structured storage file, or delete it.
NoteNote

To open or modify DTS packages, a separate download of the DTS designer components is required. See the section, Installing Design-time Support for SQL Server 2000 DTS Packages. DTS packages cannot be opened or modified directly in BI Development Studio.
```

The Integration Services database-level roles grant rights on the Integration Services system tables in the msdb database, but not on the DTS system tables, such as sysdtspackages in the msdb database. You have to grant users rights on the DTS system tables before they can perform certain management tasks, such as importing a DTS package in Management Studio. For information about the Integration Services database-level roles, see Using Integration Services Roles.

Arrow icon used with Back to Top linkBack to the top of this section
Installing Run-time Support for SQL Server 2000 DTS Packages

Although you can run DTS packages and Integration Services packages on the same computer, SQL Server 2008 does not install run-time support for DTS packages. You have to install this run-time support before you can run and manage DTS packages. For information about how to install run-time support for DTS, see How to: Install Support for Data Transformation Services Packages.

The backward compatibility files that provide run-time support for DTS packages also include run-time support for the SQL Server 2000 Analysis Services Processing task and its dependency, Decision Support Objects (DSO). However, the backward compatibility files do not include design-time support for modifying DTS packages that contain the SQL Server 2000 Analysis Services Processing task. You can modify packages that contain this task only when you have SQL Server 2000 Analysis Services installed on the same computer.

The backward compatibility files that provide run-time support for DTS packages do not include support for the SQL Server 2000 Data Mining Prediction Query task.

Arrow icon used with Back to Top linkBack to the top of this section
Running SQL Server 2000 DTS Packages at the Command Prompt

You can run DTS packages at the command prompt. Integration Services installs the dtsrun.exe utility when it installs DTS run-time support.

Arrow icon used with Back to Top linkBack to the top of this section
Running SQL Server 2000 DTS Packages from SQL Server Agent Jobs

To run DTS packages from a SQL Server Agent job, you must set the job step to Operating system (CmdExec) and use the dtsrun utility (dtsrun.exe) to run the package. You cannot set the job step to SQL Server Integration Services Package. For more information, see How to: Run a Package.

Arrow icon used with Back to Top linkBack to top of this section
Running SQL Server 2000 DTS Packages from Integration Services Packages

You can also run DTS packages as part of an Integration Services package. Integration Services provides the Execute DTS 2000 Package task for running DTS packages within an Integration Services package. For more information, see Execute DTS 2000 Package Task.

Arrow icon used with Back to Top linkBack to top of this section
Installing Design-time Support for SQL Server 2000 DTS Packages

DTS packages cannot be opened or modified directly in Business Intelligence Development Studio. In addition, neither SQL Server 2008, nor SQL Server 2005, installs the DTS package designer for modifying DTS packages. However, you can download and install the DTS package designer, and use it to modify DTS packages. For information about how to install design-time support for DTS packages, see How to: Install Support for Data Transformation Services Packages. After installing this download, you can view and modify DTS packages from Management Studio, or from the Execute DTS 2000 Package Task Editor in Business Intelligence Development Studio.

For information about how to manage certain DTS application properties that affect the DTS design environment, see Setting DTS Application Properties.

Arrow icon used with Back to Top linkBack to top of this section
Migrating SQL Server 2000 DTS Packages

SQL Server provides the DTS Package Migration Wizard for migrating DTS packages to the Integration Services package format. When you select Integration Services for installation, Setup also installs the DTS Package Migration Wizard. You can optionally use the DTS Package Migration Wizard to upgrade DTS packages to the Integration Services format. During migration, the wizard copies the DTS packages and then re-creates them in the Integration Services format. The source packages are left intact and are not modified.
NoteNote

The DTS Package Migration Wizard is available in the following editions of SQL Server: Standard, Enterprise, and Developer.

Many packages can be fully migrated to Integration Services, especially DTS packages that use tasks, connections, and other objects that have an equivalent in Integration Services. Other packages can be migrated successfully by encapsulating certain tasks or features that cannot be migrated in an Execute DTS 2000 Package task. For more information, see Migrating Data Transformation Services Packages.

Before running the DTS Package Migration Wizard, you might want to install and run Upgrade Advisor to analyze your existing packages for migration issues. For more information, see Using Upgrade Advisor to Prepare for Upgrades.
NoteNote

Upgrade Advisor cannot analyze, and the DTS Package Migration Wizard cannot migrate, DTS packages that are saved in the msdb database of an instance of SQL Server 7.0. However, the Upgrade Advisor can analyze, and the DTS Package Migration Wizard can migrate, SQL Server 7.0 DTS packages that are saved as structured storage files. Also, the Upgrade Advisor can analyze, and the DTS Package Migration Wizard can migrate, SQL Server 7.0 DTS packages that are saved in the msdb database of an instance of SQL Server 7.0 that has been upgraded to SQL Server 2005 or a later version.

Arrow icon used with Back to Top linkBack to the top of this section
Migrating Command Lines for Executing Packages

To understand how the command-line options for the SQL Server 2000 DTS dtsrun utility (dtsrun.exe) map to the options for the Integration Services dtexec utility (dtexec.exe), see Mapping dtsrun Options to dtexec Options.

Arrow icon used with Back to Top linkBack to the top of this section
Support for ODBC Data Sources

To load or save data to an ODBC data source, you can use an ADO.NET source or destination and select the .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC. It is also possible to use the Script component to create an ad hoc ODBC source or destination for use in a single package. For more information, see Creating an ODBC Destination with the Script Component.

Arrow icon used with Back to Top linkBack to the top of this section
Support for Meta Data Services (Repository) Packages

SQL Server 2000 Meta Data Services, typically known as the Repository, is a deprecated component. SQL Server 2005 and later versions do not install or use the Repository.

The DTS designer and the dtsrun utility continue to support DTS packages that were saved to the Repository.

Integration Services supports the Repository only in the Upgrade Advisor and the DTS Package Migration Wizard, and only if the Repository redistributable files are installed on the local computer. (These files are normally present when the computer has either SQL Server 2000 or the SQL Server 2000 tools installed.) When the Repository redistributable files are present, the Upgrade Advisor can scan, and the DTS Package Migration Wizard can migrate, DTS packages that were saved to the Repository. When the Repository redistributable files are not present, the Upgrade Advisor and the DTS Package Migration Wizard can only be used on DTS packages that were saved to SQL Server or to structured storage files.

The Integration Services Execute DTS 2000 Package task cannot run a DTS package that was saved to the Repository. However, the SQL Server 2000 DTS runtime can run such a package. Thus, to have an Integration Services package run a DTS package that is stored in the Repository, follow these steps:

```
Make sure that the Repository files are installed on the computer that is running the Integration Services package. To install the Repository files, install SQL Server 2000, the SQL Server 2000 tools, or the Repository redistributable files on the local computer

Create a new DTS package to act as a wrapper for the DTS package that is stored in the Repository. In this DTS wrapper package, use an Execute Package task to execute the package that is stored in the Repository. Save this wrapper package to SQL Server or as a structured storage file.

Use an Execute DTS 2000 Package task in the Integration Services package to run the new DTS wrapper package.
```

Arrow icon used with Back to Top linkBack to the top of this section
Support for SQL Server 2000 DTS Packages in SQL Server Express

SQL Server Express does not include Integration Services nor does it support DTS packages. However, you can work with DTS packages on a server that is running SQL Server Express by using one of the following methods:

```
To run existing DTS packages on a server that is running SQL Server Express, you need the DTS runtime on the server. Although SQL Server Express does not include the DTS runtime, you can install the DTS runtime on the server by either installing the SQL Server 2000 client tools or the DTS redistributable files.

To modify existing DTS packages on a server that is running SQL Server Express, you can use the SQL Server 2000 tools. You can also modify the packages remotely in SQL Server Management Studio on a server that is running one of these versions of SQL Server: Workgroup, Standard, Enterprise, or Developer. SQL Server Express does not include SQL Server Management Studio.

To migrate existing DTS packages to Integration Services, you need the DTS Package Migration Wizard that is installed with Integration Services. SQL Server Express does not include this wizard. To run the wizard, you can use one of these versions of SQL Server: Standard, Enterprise, or Developer.
```

Arrow icon used with Back to Top linkBack to the top of this section

Integration Services icon (small) Stay Up to Date with Integration Services

```
For the latest downloads, articles, samples, and videos from Microsoft, as well as selected solutions from the community, visit the Integration Services page on MSDN:

    Visit the Integration Services page on MSDN


For automatic notification of these updates, subscribe to the RSS feeds available on the page.
```

See Also
Concepts
Known DTS Package Migration Issues
Mapping dtsrun Options to dtexec Options
Setting DTS Application Properties
64 bit Considerations for Integration Services

Answer (score 3):

DTS packages can still run as before when you have the SQL Server 2008 database engine installed. To accomplish this, you **must have the Microsoft SQL Server Backward Compatibility feature installed** from the SQL Server installation media or the Feature Pack Web page. This installs the DTS runtime for SQL Server 2008, which works on 32-bit platforms only.

After you install this feature the **Legacy** folder will appear under **Management** node

[image]

[see more...](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768544%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

For 64bit runtime follow [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24793) (Feature Pack for Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - December 2008) and from the list of available downloads select **SQLServer2005_BC_x64.msi**

[image]

Comment: Sadly, my local development computer is a 64-bit Windows 7 computer with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Database installed on it, and based on what the MSDN support webapages say, I can Not install the Microsoft SQL Server Backward Compatibility feature on my local development computer. Any suggesions?